# trying to configure next-auth signin page, but having a problem with getProviders()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, next-auth

Hello fellow programmers,

I am building a nextJs app using next-auth for user sign-in. I have created the [...nextauth].js file in "pages/api/auth" and a signin.js file in "pages/auth/", the code for these files is written below for reference. the problem I am having is that I am constantly getting the following error when I try to access to signin page: "TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object"

below is a list of the dependencies in the project and their corresponding versions:

"dependencies": {
"@heroicons/react": "^1.0.5",
"@tailwindcss/forms": "^0.3.4",
"faker": "^5.5.3",
"firebase": "^9.4.0",
"next": "latest",
"next-auth": "^4.0.0-beta.7",
"react": "^17.0.2",
"react-dom": "^17.0.2",
"tailwind-scrollbar-hide": "^1.0.4"
},

[..nextauth].js code:

```js
import NextAuth from "next-auth";
import GithubProvider from "next-auth/providers/github";

export default NextAuth({
  // Configure one or more authentication providers
  providers: [
    GithubProvider({
      clientId: process.env.GITHUB_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.GITHUB_SECRET,
    }),
  ],

  pages: {
    signIn: "/auth/signin",
  },
});
```

signin.js code:

```js
import { getProviders, signIn as signIntoProvider } from "next-auth/react";

function signIn({ providers }) {
  return (
    <>
      {Object.values(providers).map((provider) => (
        <div key={provider.name}>
          <button
            onClick={() => {
              signIntoProvider(provider.id);
            }}
          >
            Sign In with {provider.name}
          </button>
        </div>
      ))}
    </>
  );
}
export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
  const providers = await getProviders();

  return {
    props: {
      providers,
    },
  };
}

export default signIn;
```

[Error Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iMDes.png)

console logging "providers" displays "null" so I believe getProviders is not working properly for some reason. Any idea why this is happening?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4):

I've fixed that by moving getProviders into state...

```
const SignIn = () => {
  const [providers, setProviders] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      const res = await getProviders();
      setProviders(res);
    })();
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      {providers &&
        Object.values(providers).map((provider) => (
          <div key={provider.name}>
            <button
              onClick={() => {
                signIn(provider.id);
              }}
            >
              Sign in with {provider.name}
            </button>
          </div>
        ))}
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: not working.
Same issue i was using Ts module but even with js its not working.

Comment: works like a charm if your navbar is in global layout component and needs to be passed down, thanks man

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. I tried console logging the result of await getProviders and it couldn't fetch as it was trying to fetch https://localhost:3000/api/auth/providers instead of http://localhost:3000/api/auth/providers.

I had the wrong NEXTAUTH_URL in my .env.local. It should be http://localhost:3000 not https://localhost:3000.

Comment: For me this worked. Was working locally but not in production. So, I have seen the NEXTAUTH_URL has the same value for the both environments. I just fixed, and worked :)

Answer (score 0):

I use the following and have no problem pulling in the providers to display them on my custom signin.

```
export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
  const providers = await getProviders(context)
  return {
    props: { providers },
  }
}
```

As you can see the getProviders is also being passed the context.

Answer (score -1):

I encountered same error. It was due to having other react application running on the same port ...